# How to submit an InfoPath form to a SharePoint List via email?

Tags: infopath, custom-form

I want to some users to submit some data via a form (InfoPath) sent by email in such a way that the form data is captured in the list.

i.e.

- Form is sent in an Email alert.
- The data filled in the form (in email) gets saved on sharepoint.
- Later reports can be generated from the data in the list.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: [Send InfoPath 2010 Form In Email](http://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/send-infopath-2010-form-in-email/)

Comment: Hi Could you insert the details of the answer. As this is an external link, this can be invalid in any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Infopath form using the Email template that will embed the form into the email so the user doesn't require the Infopath client. Then create a submit button to help apply validation and fix the email address that the form will be submitted to.

In your SharePoint library, go to the library settings and configure the library to accept submissions via email, enter the email address for the library and then use this same email address to submit the form to.